# MySQL join on substring

Tags: mysql, substring, inner-join

I have a long list of strings in a column in various formats. I would like to search for that substring and then organize that column while leaving the original column.

There is one table with 8 columns, one of which contains strings. There is also a list of words in another table. I would like to match those the words in the list with those string as an additional column. This would be so in the large table of "Tom","tom","tom az", "Tom Hanks", would have another column that just has "Tom" (the corresponding match in the list) for all of them.

I have thought about using the JOIN function, but wasn't sure how to do that with substrings. 
The excel logic would be something along the lines of "=IF((SEARCH("Tom","asfj Tom dsf")),"
TOM","NULL").

If there is more than one match is found, I would like to use the one with earlier 'ID' ( a column of integers from 1 - 11mil).

Comment: A screenshot of excel on an external site is not the way to do questions here. Put the info in the question... possibly the code logic, not the screenshot.

Comment: I appreciate the help. I was have trouble explaining my words, but hopefully the logic is helpful.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? That may help somewhat. Are the values in the list constants? Do they reside in another table? Or what?

Comment: MYSQL. There is a table with 8 columns, one of which contains strings. There is also a list of words in another table. I would like to match those the words in the list with those string as an additional column. This would be so in the large table of "Tom","tom","tom az", "Tom Hanks", would have another column that just has "Tom" (the corresponding match in the list) for all of them.

Comment: Ok... please put all this info in the question itself. Also specify what you expect when that string contains more than one of the search words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is still a bit ambiguous. You should really show the table structure, sample data and expected results.

Supposing you have this minimal structure and data:

```
CREATE TABLE People (
  id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  FullName TEXT
);
INSERT INTO People (FullName) VALUES ('Tom Hanks');
INSERT INTO People (FullName) VALUES ('Mary 467');
INSERT INTO People (FullName) VALUES ('ann margaret' );
INSERT INTO People (FullName) VALUES ('ziddy tom');
INSERT INTO People (FullName) VALUES ('bloody mary');
INSERT INTO People (FullName) VALUES ('mary ann');

CREATE TABLE Names (
  id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  Name TEXT
);  
INSERT INTO Names (Name) VALUES ('Tom' );
INSERT INTO Names (Name) VALUES ('Mary');
INSERT INTO Names (Name) VALUES ('Ann' );
```

... then you can get a first result with a query like this:

```
SELECT p.*, n.Name
FROM People p
JOIN Names  n ON p.FullName LIKE CONCAT('%',LOWER(n.Name),'%');
```

(tested on [SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31b36b/2))

There are some problems though.

1. It's not clear if you want to search whole word only. Your Excel sample does not do that, so I stuck with a simple LIKE. To search for whole words the LIKE will not work properly.
2. "mary ann" comes up twice because that FullName contains two of the Names. You said you'd like to choose one depending on ID, but it's not clear if you understood the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I think I have figured out what I was trying to do. Help was very much appreciated.

Comment: For anyone looking at this in the current year, I found that the INSTR function was faster for my data (around 3200 rows joined with 2000).  Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_instr.asp